# Get image by Content Key added by the User, using ContentReference in code's metadata

Tags: metadata, community-builder, images, content, experience-builder-page

I'm new to Salesforce and I'm stuck with showing an imaged added by ContentReference, when adding the image in the Experience Builder it returns a Content Key like this "MCTYRWQGOBCVHMHHLCSYZ2PWXQVQ", but how can I use it to show the selected image in the builder and in the web page I'm building? I tried this solution ([Spring'21 Use CMS Content in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/333877/spring21-use-cms-content-in-lwc)) and adapted it but it throws me the following error :

```
app:9 [webruntime] router level error 
error:  Proxy {} 
wcstack:
   <webruntime-app>
    <webruntime-router-container>
    <webruntimedesign-component-wrapper>
    <webruntimedesign-design-component>
    <webruntimedesign-component-wrapper>
    <webruntimedesign-design-component>
    <c-my-first-l-w-c>
    <lightning-layout-item>
```

Not sure what is happening or what shoul I do, again I'm very new to salesforce. This is my code:

HTML:

```html
<template>
  <p>this is the leadlist {contentId}</p>
  <img src={contentId} data-contentkey={contentId} class="image"></img>
  <lightning-button variant="brand" label={bntLabel} title="Primary action" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
</template>
```

JS:

```js
import getManagedContentByContentKeys from '@salesforce/apex/leadList.getManagedContentByContentKeys';
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';

export default class LeadList extends LightningElement {

  @api bntLabel;
  @api contentId;

  handleClick = () => {
      console.log("You clicked me!")
      console.log('contentId', this.contentId)
  }

  @wire(getManagedContentByContentKeys, { managedContentIds: this.contentId})
  managedContent({ error, data }) {
      console.log('it entered the function:');

    if (data) {
      console.log('data:');
      console.log({data});
      // Assign data to a variable which you can use in your HTML.
    
    } else if (error) {
      console.log('error:', error);
     // Handle the error. 
    }
  }
}
```

Metadata:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
  <isExposed>true</isExposed>
  <targets>
      <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
      <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
  </targets>
  <targetConfigs>
      <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
          <property name="bntLabel" type="String" default="click"></property>
          <property type="ContentReference" name="contentId" label="Content ID"></property>
      </targetConfig>
  </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Apex class:

```java
public with sharing class leadList {
  public leadList() {

  }

  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static String getManagedContentByContentKeys(String communityId, String[] managedContentIds, Integer pageParam, Integer pageSize, String language, String managedContentType, Boolean showAbsoluteUrl){
    return 'hola';//ConnectApi.ManagedContent.getManagedContentByContentKeys(communityId, managedContentIds, pageParam, pageSize, language, managedContentType, showAbsoluteUrl);
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are a few minor bugs in the code and that is the reason you aren't having much luck.

Firstly, the `@wire` method in the LWC requires an array of managedContentIds, not just a single one. The syntax for the dynamic variable is also incorrect ([LWC Documentation: Wire Adapters](https://lwc.dev/guide/wire_adapter#wire-adapters)).

```js
import getManagedContentByContentKeys from '@salesforce/apex/leadList.getManagedContentByContentKeys';
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';

export default class LeadList extends LightningElement {
  @api bntLabel;
  @api contentId;

  // Added the contentId to an array of contentIds
  get managedContentIds() {
    return [this.contentId]
  }

  handleClick = () => {
      console.log("You clicked me!")
      console.log('contentId', this.contentId)
  }

  // Fix the syntax for dynamic props for `@wire` methods.
  @wire(getManagedContentByContentKeys, { managedContentIds: '$managedContentIds'})
  managedContent({ error, data }) {
    if (error) {
      console.error('error:', error);
    } else if (data) {
      console.log('data: ', data);

      // destructure the properties we want from the response object
      const {
        managedContentId,
        contentNodes: { source, altText, title },
      } = data

      // Data here should be set to a property for the html to render
      this.image = {
        url: source ? source.unauthenticatedUrl : '',
        alt: altText ? altText.value : '',
        title: title ? title.value : '',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The apex method also returns a test string (I assume this was a mistake returning `"hola"`). You can also set the extra properties to `null`/`true` if you don't intend on passing them.

```java
public with sharing class leadList {
  public leadList() { }

  @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
  public static String getManagedContentByContentKeys(String communityId, String[] managedContentIds){
    return ConnectApi.ManagedContent.getManagedContentByContentKeys(
      communityId,
      managedContentIds,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      true
    );
  }
}
```

Lastly, the html should render the `this.image` we set above in the javascript. Instead of assigning `contentId` to the `<img src={contentId}/>`, it should use the `this.image` reference, `<img src={image.url} alt={image.alt}/>`

```html
<template>
  <p>this is the leadlist {contentId}</p>
  <img src={image.url} alt={image.alt} class="image"></img>
  <lightning-button variant="brand" label={bntLabel} title="Primary action" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
</template>
```